# How to pass the onchange value into the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-js

I am working on the office.js and I'm trying to pass the selected dropdown value `onchange` but it is throwing `null`. I don't know what the problem is. If I hard code the value it is working fine. How can i fix it?

```
$("select").change({ "name": this.value }, fname)

async function fname(e) {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      console.log(e.data.exname)
    })
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Firstly note that `this` will not be the `select` in your first line of code. Secondly, it makes far more sense to just read the value from the DOM within the `fname` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{ "name": this.value }` isn't valid. For finding the object that triggered the event, you can use [`$(this)`](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified) within an anonymous handler.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        console.log($(this).data.exname)
    })
});
```

One note, `$("select")` will actually wire this event up for *every* drop down on your page. Depending on what you're doing, this might not be the right model. When you're going to act on specific values, typically you only want to wire up a single `select` element by it's `id` using the `#` prefix: `$(#SelectId)`.